# C++ Maths in Switch statements

Tags: c++, math

So I am looking to do a simple maths equation that prints a menu and then takes in the Operator as a `char`. Then, it prompts the user into entering two numbers and then prints the resulting question and then answer in a format such as: `10 + 20 = 30`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variables
    char op_choice;
    int usrnum_1;
    int usrnum_2;

    //Menu
    cout << "Operator Menu\n\n";
    cout << "+\n";
    cout << "-\n";
    cout << "*\n";
    cout << "/\n";
    cout << "%\n\n";

    cout << "Choice:";
    cin >> op_choice;
    cout << "\nNumbers:";
    cout << "\n\nEnter TWO numbers to complete an arithmitic operation with the " << op_choice << " operator: \n";
    cout << "eg: 1 + 2 = 3\n";
    cout << "\nNumber 1: ";
    cin >> usrnum_1;
    cout << "Number 2: ";
    cin >> usrnum_2;

    switch (op_choice)
    {
        case '+':
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << "\nYou picked " << usrnum_1 << " - " << usrnum_2 << " = ";
            cout << usrnum_1 - usrnum_2;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << "\nYou picked " << usrnum_1 << " X " << usrnum_2 << " = ";
            cout << usrnum_1 * usrnum_2;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << "\nYou picked " << usrnum_1 << " / " << usrnum_2 << " = ";
            cout << usrnum_1 / usrnum_2;
            break;
        case '%':
            cout << "\nYou picked " << usrnum_1 << " % " << usrnum_2 << " = ";
            cout << usrnum_1 % usrnum_2;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\nYou made an illegal choice.\n";
    }

    cout << "\nYou picked " << usrnum_1 << " " <<  op_choice << " " <<  usrnum_2 << " = ";
    cout << usrnum_1 << op_choice << usrnum_2;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I have actually got this code working as you can see from the subtraction and multiplication etc. But I'm looking to get the cout outside the switch block (which I started doing and was testing with add). Is there a way to make this work without making op_choice into an int originally? Or putting the cout statement into the switch block? Would it be better to use an  if-else-if statement?

Comment: Why don't you just have a variable to store the answer? You already store the operator character and the values the user puts in. In the switch statement, just perform the calculation and store the value, then at the end print out using one cout only.

Comment: You mean you want to print the result of the math operation outside the `switch`? How about storing it in a variable and print that?

Comment: A more general formulation of the other comments: separate the calculation of the result from the displaying of the result.

Comment: To get a good question (so I can upvote it), you should clarify what “does not work” means, i.e. what is the expected and actual output. See [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `switch` is the best code construct for this kind of code.

The problem is that your concept of a universal output

```
cout << usrnum_1 << op_choice << usrnum_2;
```

cannot become anything near to the calculation you want to do:

```
cout << usrnum_1 + usrnum_2;
```

1. I hope the first problem is clear when you see these lines close to each other. They simply do different things:

   1. The first one prints `usrnum_1`, then `op_choice` and finally `usrnum_2`. No magic happens, `op_choice` is just a `char` to be printed.
   2. The second one does the addition `usrnum_1 + usrnum_2` (arithmetic operators have a [higher priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the bitwise shifting operator `<<`) and then prints the result of the addition.
2. The second, more important problem is that `char op_choice = '+'` (set in runtime) cannot easily become an arithmetic operator `+` in the C++ code since it’s a compiled language. The *compiler* takes the expression `a + b` and translates it to the machine instruction for integer addition. Your *compiled program* has no idea that the instruction for integer addition is related to the number 43 (the ASCII code of `+`) until you tell it explicitly (using `switch`, preferably).

So how to make it work? As commenters suggested, you have to keep the calculation in the `switch` block and bring only the print part out of it.

```
int result;

switch (op_choice)
{
    case '+':
        result = usrnum_1 + usrnum_2;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = usrnum_1 - usrnum_2;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = usrnum_1 * usrnum_2;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = usrnum_1 / usrnum_2;
        break;
    case '%':
        result = usrnum_1 % usrnum_2;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\nYou made an illegal choice.\n";
        return 1;
}

cout << "\nYou picked " << usrnum_1 << " " <<  op_choice << " " <<  usrnum_2 << " = ";
cout << result;
```

[Online demo of the program](https://ideone.com/xpi1Cc)